# Use Facebook Graph API with Django

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am doing a test project that uses Facebook Graph API to retrieve data from an events page. I need to use the following url: https://graph.facebook.com/OffTheGridSF/events and do a HTTP GET from my web app. I created a facebook app (for testing) and have the APP_ID, APP_SECRET. I was wondering which library (if any) should I use. I have looked at django-facebook and pyfb. I am not sure how the authentication process works. I don't need a login page for my website. I only need the JSON containing the list of events. Any help as to how I should proceed will be highly appreciated. I just started playing around with Django a few hours ago so nothing is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using python requests library directly with the URL you want to GET. Checkout [requests-oathlib](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib)

Comment: I managed to use the requests library to get a response object. But it is of content-type: text/html. I was hoping for a JSON object. I tried to covert it to json using simplejson but I am getting decoding errors. Any help?

Comment: the request object has a '.json' method, have you tried using that? Otherwise I'd need to see your exact errors.